# Typescript compiling a .d.ts file and get error

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I'm using NestJS and i'm trying to instantiate a prismic.io client using the following statement

```
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import Prismic from '@prismicio/client';

export const PrismicClientRef = Symbol();

export const prismicClientProvider = {
  provide: PrismicClientRef,
  useFactory: (config: ConfigService) =>
    Prismic.client(config.get('PRISMIC_URL') as string, {
      accessToken: config.get('PRISMIC_ACCESS_TOKEN') as string,
    }),
  inject: [ConfigService],
};
```

Then I'm injecting this client inside a repository but I need to import Default client type from a .d.ts

```
import { Inject, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { DefaultClient } from '@prismicio/client/types/client';
import { Product } from 'src/payment/domain/Product';
import { PrismicProductMapper } from 'src/payment/infra/mappers/PrismicProductMapper';
import { PrismicClientRef } from '../client';

@Injectable()
export class PrismicRepository {
  constructor(@Inject(PrismicClientRef) private client: DefaultClient) {}
```

I'm getting it from `import { DefaultClient } from '@prismicio/client/types/client';`

But the thing is that the compiled js output `const client_1 = require("@prismicio/client/types/client");` which result of a crash because this file doesn't exists.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

```
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import Prismic from '@prismicio/client';

export const PrismicClientRef = Symbol();

export const prismicClientProvider = {
  provide: PrismicClientRef,
  useFactory: (config: ConfigService) =>
    Prismic.client(config.get('PRISMIC_URL') as string, {
      accessToken: config.get('PRISMIC_ACCESS_TOKEN') as string,
    }),
  inject: [ConfigService],
};

export type PrismicClient = ReturnType<typeof prismicClientProvider['useFactory']>;
```

I achieved to get typings of the client doing this trick …